# Jackson JSON exception at deserialization

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have problem using `Jackson` library in order to deserialize JSON string and map it into `POJO`.

I have this json:

```
[{
    "requestor": "Nick Jagger",
    "smtp": "test@email.com",
    "smtp_from": "test2@email.com",
    "cnname": "testcn",
    "date": "2014-11-11",
    "system_ciid": "3926598",
    "request_base64": "its some base64 hash"
}, {
    "requestor": "Freddie Mercury",
    "smtp": "test@email.com",
    "smtp_from": "test2@email.com",
    "cnname": "testowe cn",
    "date": "2014-11-26",
    "system_ciid": "JK19",
    "request_base64": "some base64 hash"
}]
```

I have created POJO class to represent one element in this array:

```
public class Questionareimplements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @JsonProperty("cnname")
    private String caName;
    @JsonProperty("smtp")
    private String smtp;
    @JsonProperty("requestor")
    private String issuer;
    @JsonProperty("system_ciid")
    private String system_ciid;
    @JsonProperty("date")
    private String date;
    @JsonProperty("request_base64")
    private String base64String;
    @JsonProperty("smtp_from")
    private String smtp2;


    // getters and setters
}
```

And a class which represent list of those objects:

```
public class QuestionareList {

    private List<Questionare> questionares;

    public List<Questionare> getQuestionares() {
        return questionares;
    }

    public void setQuestionares(List<Questionare> questionares) {
        this.questionares = questionares;
    }
}
```

And now how I map those

```
QuestionareList listQ = new QuestionareList();

ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper();

listQ = m.readValue(jsonString,QuestionareList.class);
```

All I get is:

```
Can not deserialize instance of com.test.service.QuestionareList out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@27d525; line: 1, column: 1]
```

Any idea what Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am considering that you already have 2 jars i.e. 
        **1.  Jackson Core
        2.  Jackson Mapper**

So for Parsing from JSON to Your POJO

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JavaType javaType=mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class,Questionare.class);

QuestionareList listQ = new QuestionareList();
listQ.setQuestionares(mapper.readValue(jsonString,javaType));
```

Or if we can do it in your way

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JavaType javaType=mapper.getTypeFactory().constructType(QuestionareList.class);

    QuestionareList listQ = new QuestionareList();
    listQ = mapper.readValue(jsonString,javaType);
```

and thats it !.

Answer (score 0):

QuestionareList requirs json object which has array field, but you json string is just an array.
You can use the following to deserialize array to List
List questionares =m.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference>() {});

Comment: Thank You for anwser, but using `listQ = m.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<SslQuestionareList>() {});` instead of `listQ = m.readValue(jsonString,QuestionareList.class);` change nothing. i still get same exception :(

Comment: I tried with the following, it works fine for me.
ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper();
List<Questionare> questionares = m.readValue("[{\"cnname\":\"testcn\"},{\"cnname\":\"testowe cn\"}]", new TypeReference<List<Questionare>>() {});